# Outline numbering. The text indent goes to 1.6 on "VIII" and I can't change it

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I made my own outline system, (does this with the stock outline numbering also).  I set text the indent to 0.5 for all levels.  When I get to VIII on the list, it jumps to 1.6.  If I hit enter to IX, it goes back to 0.5.

If I edit VIII to 0.5, it changes the whole row to 1.6, and leaves VIII at 0.5 text indent.  How do I fix this!?  I haven't been this frustrated in a while.  I'm writing a contract for a company and I need this to be perfect.

I've tried using the stock outline numbering, I've tried making a new document, I've tried restarting, I tried making my own outline list, etc.  I've searched google but I don't know exactly how to word it without writing 160 words.

Comment: As a workaround, could you make your left margin narrower and increase the indent? Presumably you would have to increase the indent for everything, not just these paragraphs.